# Polygon Barriers error when creation network service area in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, barriers

I have encountered an error when creating a service area using the park location in the local area. The service area was successfully created, and everything is excellent, except for the Polygon Barriers. I added a water area polygon as my Polygon Barrier, and then an error message appeared: "Polygon Barriers" has no associated network location information." I have checked every possibility for this issue, and the coordinate systems also appear to be correct.

What could be the cause of this problem?

I am using ArcMap 10.5 version."